# Assertion failure in GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm clustersAtZoom

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

So my app keep crashing giving me this error [Assertion failure in GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm clustersAtZoom] , then after while of reaching I found that the itemToClusterDistanceMap and itemToClusterMap alway one item less than the _items.count ,but I do not the reason for this behaviour

```
NSAssert(itemToClusterDistanceMap.count == _items.count,
           @"All items should be mapped to a distance");
  NSAssert(itemToClusterMap.count == _items.count,
          @"All items should be mapped to a cluster");
    func initMapMarkersWithClustering(){
        let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
        let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
        let renderer = CustomClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)

        generateClusterItems()
        clusterManager.cluster()

        clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone how may face this issue in the feature I found the issue the position.latitude and position.longitude should be in the rage of [-85,85] for latitude and [-180,180] for longitude and not 0 for both before adding them